# What is causing this warning in symfit?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, symfit

Consider this simple optimization code:

```
from symfit import *


x1 = 1
x2 = 4
p1, p2 = parameters('p1, p2')
model = p1*p2
constraints = [
    Eq(x1*p1+(x2-x1)*p2, 1),
    Ge(p1, p2),
    Ge(p2, 0)
    ]

fit = Fit(- model, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/symfit/core/fit.py:1783: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return 1 - SS_res/SS_tot
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `symfit` currently always tries to calculate the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) (R^2) for the fit. In this case, since there is no data, both SS_res and SS_tot are zero, resulting in a 0/0 and hence the warning and the resulting `nan` in `fit_results`.

We are now adding extra intelligence to `FitResults` such that it won't be calculated in the first place, but it is safe to ignore this warning.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. You may notice I have now made a symfit tag too.

Comment: I did notice, thanks a bunch! Ironically your question just got me the reputation needed to be allowed to create it myself, but took away the need for me to do it :P.